# Font File Location

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm trying to locate/figure out the location of the font file of this [site](https://globalleadershipfoundation.com/). 
I know the site is using Helvetica font. I just can't seem to find the font file or how it was embedded.

I did search the whole site directory using ftp and found a Helvetica.php file... It's my first time seeing that type font file with PHP extension.

Thanks!

Comment: super crazy plan ... ask them

Comment: forgot to say that i don't have contact w/ the developer who made the site anymore

Comment: http://codepad.org/kMHf2DFe here's the code inside Helvetica.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Helvetica` is a default (web-safe) font.

`Helvetica Neue` is a premium font. It is currently NOT loaded into the site, and it is defaulting to `Helvetica` instead. The previous developer probably forgot to include TypeKit.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7qxcdb  according to the css, it does use Helvetica Neue ? Does it?

Comment: so if i add this line of css in the new site .. 

body {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color:#545454;
}

it will use the same font which is Helvatica, not Neue?

Comment: Alright, makes sense... a follow up question: why is that i can't do a font-weight: 200 just like the original site? http://prntscr.com/7qxkxs

Comment: why the original site was able to use 200?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82882/discussion-between-jeremi-liwanag-and-samuel-liew).